# How to know if an App still has access to OneDrive through Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I have an application which is using OneDrive through Microsoft Graph API, I created an App and users will consent through the oauth2 flow (that's working).

Now, after that, I have a *refreshToken* that I can use to get more *accessToken* (that's also working).

The problem comes when the user revokes the access of my App from their OneDrive account, the *refreshToken* is still valid and my code still has access to OneDrive user's data.

Is there a way to know that my app was revoked for this specific user through the Microsoft Graph API?

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone in the future, Microsoft Graph API do invalidate the *refreshToken*. For some unknown reason it was taking more than 10 minutes for making the invalidation.

After multiple times of testing this I saw that sometimes it might take 1 minute to invalidate, 5 minutes or even 10.

Because it might help someone I'm going to put the exact errors that I got when this case happened so people can handle it gracefully:

```
{"error": "invalid_grant", "error_codes": [65001], "error_description": "AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'your_app_id_here' named 'your_app_name_here'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource."}
```